# Can a table run in a php while loop?

Tags: php, html

I am attempting to create a table that constantly pulls data from a database via a query, but I can not get my table to display whatsoever when I put it inside a while loop that I need to constantly get the data. Am i simply doing something wrong with my code or is this not a possible thing? I will post both the css and html
EDIT 2: This is the calculations for variables such as $diff

```
$str5npos = ($str5npos /100);
$str5npos = $str5npos +12.015;
$str5nposgraph = (($str5npos/40) *100);

$str5spos = ($str5spos /100);
$str5spos = $str5spos +12.015;
$str5sposgraph = (($str5spos/40) *100);
$total5= round($str5npos + $str5spos); 

$diff5 = round($str5npos - $str5spos);
$direction5 = 'North';
if ($diff5 < 0) {
    $direction5 = 'South';
}
```

EDIT: HERE IS MY QUERY

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM p4updates WHERE DB4PrimeKey = 4");

// Fetch live values from data base
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $str1npos = $row['str1npos'];$str1spos = $row['str1spos'];$str2npos = $row['str2npos'];$str2spos = $row['str2spos'];$str3npos = $row['str3npos'];
    $str3spos = $row['str3spos'];$str4npos = $row['str4npos'];$str4spos = $row['str4spos']; $str5npos = $row['str5npos'];
    $str5spos = $row['str5spos'];$str6npos = $row['str6npos'];$str6spos = $row['str6spos'];$str7npos = $row['str7npos'];
    $str7spos = $row['str7spos'];$wrnpos = $row['wrnpos'];$wrspos = $row['wrspos'];

    $strout1 = $row['strout1'];$strout2 = $row['strout2'];$strout3 = $row['strout3'];$strout4 = $row['strout4'];$strout5 = $row['strout5'];
    $strout6 = $row['strout6'];$strout7 = $row['strout7'];$wrout4 = $row['wrout4'];

    $strfbk1 = $row['strfbk1'];$strfbk2 = $row['strfbk2'];$strfbk3 = $row['strfbk3'];$strfbk4 = $row['strfbk4'];$strfbk5 = $row['strfbk5'];
    $strfbk6 = $row['strfbk6'];$strfbk7 = $row['strfbk7'];$wrfbk3 = $row['wrfbk3'];

    $stralm1 = $row['stralm1'];$stralm2 = $row['stralm2'];$stralm3 = $row['stralm3'];$stralm4 = $row['stralm4'];$stralm5 = $row['stralm5'];


    }
```

CSS

```
.MainTable { float: left;width:100%;  background-color:#CEF7CE;border-collapse:collapse;  font-size: 20px; }
.MainTable th { background-color:#197D19;color:white; font-size: 15px; }
.MainTable td, .MainTable th {  padding:1px;border:1px solid #000; font-size: 20px; }
```

HTML

```
  <col width="10%">
  <col width="9%">
  <col width="9%">
  <col width="9%">
  <col width="9%">
  <col width="9%">
  <col width="9%">
  <col width="9%">
  <col width="9%">


<tr>    


<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   
// Row one Entrys 

echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>" . $diff1= row['diff1'].''. $direction1 = row['direction1']. "</td>" ;
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>" . $diff2 = row['diff2'] .''.$direction2 = row['direction2']. "</td>";
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>" . $diff3= row['diff3'] .''.$direction3= row['direction3'] . "</td>"; 
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>" . $wrdiff= row['wrdiff'] .''.$wrdirection= row['wrdirection'] . "</td>"; 
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>" . $diff4= row['diff4'].''. $direction4= row['direction4'] . "</td>";
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>" . $diff5= row['diff5'] .''.$direction5= row['direction5']  ."</td>"; 
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>" . $diff6= row['diff6'] .''.$direction6= row['direction6'] ."</td>"; 
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>" . $diff7= row['diff7'].''. $direction7= row['direction7'] .  "</td>"; 
}
?>
</tr>   
<!-- Row two Entrys --> 
<tr> <?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   

echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>" .$strout1= row['strout1'] .'%'."</td>";
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>" . $strout2= row['strout2']. '%'."</td>";
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>"  .$strout3= row['strout3'] .'%'."</td>";
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>" . $wrout4= row['wrout4']. '%'."</td>";
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>" .$strout4= row['strout4'] .'%'."</td>";
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>" . $strout5= row['strout5'] .'%'."</td>";
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>"  .$strout6= row['strout6']. '%'."</td>";
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>"  .$strout7= row['strout7'] .'%'."</td>";
} ?>
</tr>
<!-- Row three Entrys -->
<tr><?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>". $strfbk1= row['strfbk1']. '%'."</td>";
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>" . $strfbk2= row['strfbk2']. '%'."</td>";
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>" . $strfbk3= row['strfbk3']. '%'."</td>";
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>" . $wrfbk3= row['wrfbk3']. '%'."</td>";
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>". $strfbk4= row['strfbk4'] .'%'."</td>";
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>" . $strfbk5= row['strfbk5']. '%'."</td>";
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>" . $strfbk6= row['strfbk6']. '%'."</td>";
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>" . $strfbk7= row['strfbk7']. '%'."</td>";
} ?> 
</tr>
<!--  Row four Entrys -->
<tr><?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   

echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>". $stralm1= row['stralm1']. '%'."</td>";
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>" . $stralm2= row['stralm2'] .'%'."</td>";
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>" . $stralm3= row['stralm3']. '%'."</td>";
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>" . '---'."</td>";
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>". $stralm4= row['stralm4'] .'%'."</td>";
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>" . $stralm5= row['stralm5'] .'%'."</td>";
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>" . '---'."</td>";
echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>" . '---'."</td>";
}
?> 
</tr>

</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, AJAX will be your friend.

Comment: Why not just: `echo "<td height ='54' align='center'>{$row['diff1']} {$row['direction1']}</td>" ;`

Comment: Is there a reason why you are alternating between single quotes  and double quotes?  I understand you are using single quotes to differentiate HTML variables, but then you jump back into single quotes for your HTML variables.  I'd stick with single  quotes for text strings and double quotes for variables within HTML

Comment: Note, your biggest problem here is you are not assigning your `$row[]` variables properly.

Comment: please show us your query, and that will help us provide the best answer

Comment: Added query hope that helps

Comment: Okay what I mean is that we need to see what keys (aka column names) you have in your tables.  Thanks

Comment: It is a single row database, with about 50 columns, each column named that variable name such as strout4

Comment: In your table you are calling rows named `diff`, `diff2`, etc.  If they do not exist in your database, they will not be returned as rows.  In other words, where are you getting those values?

Comment: They are locally created variables based on a variety of rounding and multiplication. Ill edit the post to show one of the 8 calculations.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to make some edits to my answer below, however it looks like you are doing a LOT here which would have helped.   For troubleshooting, if this is still not working, I recommend removing the CSS and just seeing if you can get the values to appear.  One piece at a time, it's good to try to get the basics working before adding the calculations.

Comment: My eyes. You should clean that up a bit...

Comment: Note re:  "is this not a possible thing? "   It's always possible, but it's easier to solve with complete information ;)   What you are trying to do is actually quite simple, but we need all the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this inside your loop.  (I'm assuming you have rows with those specific names in your table.  If not, remove the number like so `$row['direction']` and let your loop grab each variable.)

edit:  I removed the variable definition as that was overwriting and redefining what were doing above.  From what I can see, the `$diff` variables are not coming from your database above but are being calculated off of other variables from the database.  Assuming these are calculated properly and there's no error in that piece, try the below (using the example you provided above).  Note, you do not want to use `row` if the variables are not coming from a row.

```
echo '<td height ="54" align="center">' . $diff5.' '. $direction5. '</td>' ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I see the benefit of doing it this way but I still only get a single tiny green row with no text, just a small sliver across the screen that is the background color of the table

Comment: please show your query.  I have a feeling that the problem lies there

Comment: From what you are showing above, I don't see any rows names `diff1` etc

Comment: That didn't work perfect but I slowly added things back in as you suggested with a similar format and that seems to have done the trick

Comment: I always find that figuring things out myself is best :)  Glad  you got it

Answer (score 0):

is:
echo "" . $diff1= row['diff1'].''. $direction1 = row['direction1']. "" ;

try:
echo "" . $diff1= $row['diff1'].''. $direction1 = $row['direction1']. "" ;

You are missing the $ in front of $row[] in every echo statement within your while loops

Comment: Thanks for the suggeestion, i get the same results however which is a very  narrow green bar which is the background color of the table, but it has no content.